# Child element longer than Parent

Tags: css, layout

Hy, I made a simple layout using div consists of one parent element called "main" and two child elements called "header" and "content".

The example is shown on the link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/kazekagesama01/kw73F/

```
#main
{
width       : 1000px;
min-height  : 1000px;
height      : auto;
border      : 1px dashed green;
position    : absolute;
left        : 170px;
}

#header
{
width       : 100%;
height      : 250px;
border      : 1px dotted blue;
}

#content
{
width       : 100%;
height      : 1000px;
border      : 1px dotted red;
position            : relative; 
top         : 20px;
}
```

My question is, why do the layout keep making the second child element, which is "content", longer than parent element, which is "main". For your information, I've set the height of "main" to auto.

Need your help, had googled but didn't found any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the parent

```
#main
{
width       : 1000px;
min-height  : 1000px;
height      : auto;
border      : 1px solid black;
position    : absolute;
left        : 170px;
overflow    : hidden;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kw73F/2/

Answer (score 0):

`#content
{
width       : 100%;
height      : 1000px;
border      : 1px dotted red;
position    : absoulate;

top         : 20px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Why using unnecessary `positioning`. Remove `position:absolute` and `position:relative` from the layout and your layout will be fine.